# Sequelize raw query, get all data or specific data with bind (postgresql)

Tags: node.js, postgresql, express, sequelize.js

so I have product table when I select with raw query if collection not specified then it will get all data, but if the collection is specified it will get per collection. here is my code:

```
  const { category, collection } = req.query;
  const sql = `
    select 
     p.id,
     p.p_image, 
     p.p_name, 
     p.p_desc,
     p.p_prize, 
     p.p_stock,
     c.c_name,
     cl.cl_name
    from products as p
    inner join collections as cl on cl.id = p.p_collection_id 
    inner join categories as c on c.id = cl.cl_category_id
    where (c.c_name = $1 and cl.id = $2) or (c.c_name = $1)
    order by p."createdAt" desc; `;

   try {
      const getData = await Product.sequelize.query(sql, {
      bind: [category, collection],
   });
   
   if (getData[0] != "") {
       res.status(200).send({
          s: 1,
          message: "success retrive all products",
          data: getData[0],
       });
    } else {
       res.status(404).send({
          s: 0,
          message: "data not found",
       });
     }
  } catch (err) {
    res.status(500).send({
      message: err,
   });
  }
  };
```

What I like to achieve is that:

1. When `http://localhost:3001/api/v1/product/get?category=man` then I will get all data per category either `man, woman, or kid`
2. When `http://localhost:3001/api/v1/product/get?category=man&collection=1` then I will get all data per category either `man, woman or kid`, but specific collection per id `1=topwear, 2=bottomwear` etc.

What it really does when I do above:

1. It only get `message: {}` when `http://localhost:3001/api/v1/product/get?category=man`
2. It get all data and doesn't care about the collection when `http://localhost:3001/api/v1/product/get?category=man&collection=1`

I hope you can understand what I mean and can help me please....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose you need to add a condition to check passed `collection` value:

```js
 where (c.c_name = $1 and cl.id = $2 and $2 is not null) or (c.c_name = $1 and $2 is null)
```

And of course you need to pass `null` in `collection` variable if the corresponding query parameter in the url is not indicated.

P.S. It's better and more readable to use named parameters in the `bind` option and SQL query itself, like this:

```js
const sql = `
    select 
     p.id,
     p.p_image, 
     p.p_name, 
     p.p_desc,
     p.p_prize, 
     p.p_stock,
     c.c_name,
     cl.cl_name
    from products as p
    inner join collections as cl on cl.id = p.p_collection_id 
    inner join categories as c on c.id = cl.cl_category_id
    where (c.c_name = $category and cl.id = $collection and $collection is not null)
       or (c.c_name = $category and $collection is null)
    order by p."createdAt" desc; `;

   try {
      const getData = await Product.sequelize.query(sql, {
      bind: { category, collection },
   });
```

Comment: I tried your solution. It worked for `http://localhost:3001/api/v1/product/get?category=man&collection=1` I got what I wanted, but if collection is null or I don't fill it like `collection=null` or `collection=` I got error in postman says error code `code: 22P02` `parameters: [ "man",""]` for `""` and for `null` `parameters: [ "man","null"]`

Comment: You just need to pass `null` if `collection` query parameter either not indicated or doesn't have a value or have `null` string value and it does the trick

Comment: `http://localhost:3001/api/v1/product/get?category=man&collection=null` you mean like that right? I done that, but didn't get the wanted result. I got the error I mentioned above, because `collection` must be integer datatype. I tried `http://localhost:3001/api/v1/product/get?category=man` the result is `message:{}`

Comment: Did you pass `collection` like this: `(!collection || collection === 'null' ? null : parseInt(collection)`?

Comment: yes. Finally it worked, thanks so much my friend :)